# Windows 10 Taskbar. How to Filter pin suggestions in Jump list

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, jumplist

Windows Taskbar, pinned application.

I'm looking for a way to **filter** out, or hide/remove/delete automatically if you will, (not disable functionality) suggestions in the **Recent** section, based on file extension.

Show (green): *.sln*

Hide (red): *.txt, .cs, .csproj etc.*

- Do any of you know a way to filter pin suggestions?

[image: Example]

For those of you who got this far (Huzzah!): The whole point is to not drown in suggestions, every time I want to pin a specific document or solution